# Relying on a zero'ing heap for initialising members

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is it well defined behavoir to rely on a heap which zero initialises memory to initialise members to zero.

Looking at a basic POD struct:

`struct S {int i;};`

If I have (through whatever mechanism) a heap implementation which guarantees to zero out the backing memory, can I avoid zeroing out the members of my POD?

Another way to put this - is the following well defined behaviour:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
#include <assert.h>
struct S {int i;};
int main()
{
    void* backing_mem = std::aligned_alloc(alignof(S), sizeof(S));
    std::memset(backing_mem, 0, sizeof(S));
    S* s = new (backing_mem)S;
    assert(s->i == 0);

    // or assuming we've overridden the global allocator to one which zeros memory:
    S* s2 = new S;
    assert(s2->i == 0);
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/M6oY9q5xW

I understand the language has exceptions for global/statically allocated objects to be implicitly zero, and was wondering if the same happens here. Obviously this wont work for non-PODs. Please quote the standard if possible.

(Please ignore talk about optimisation here, this is a language/correctness question)

Comment: `struct S { int i=0; };' will already initialize to 0. No need to do all that stuff with alignment, alloc and memset.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I know. This question isn't about that though. I want to understand if this is correct from a language standpoint.

Comment: In general rely on higher level constructs like explicit initialization to do what you want to do. Keep away from direct calls to memset, memcpy etc..

Comment: @PepijnKramer But this is not what OP is asking about - this is a language-lawyer question.

Comment: Me bad, I missed that.  :) Looks like we depend on what the standard has to say about placement new has to say. I expect if C++ complies with you don't pay for what you don't use is that placement new will not modify the backing memory content.

Comment: @PepijnKramer sorry maybe my example was bad - I dont want to know _specifically_ about placement new. So I've updated the question to also include replacing the global allocator with one that zeros aswell. But knowing placement new specifics may well help answer this question.

Comment: This is undefined behavior: you're fine from a lifetime perspective, as per [\[basic.life\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#6), but the `s->i` is an unitialized read (from an object `S` who is within its lifetime) which is, as per [\[basic.indet\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.indet#2), undefined behaviour.

Comment: @dfrib that's what I was worried about. I was hoping that in the part of the standard which deals with global/static variables being zeros, there would be leeway to also include this construct. I'm not familiar enough with the standard to know though.

Comment: Since you are interesting in formal language aspects, it'd be worth to point out that the construct of POD is no more. It was replaced by *trivial* and friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it well defined behavoir to rely on a heap which zero initialises memory to initialise members to zero.

From a standard perspective: no.

Whilst you're fine from a lifetime perspective ([[basic.life]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#6)) the `s->i` is an uninitialized read which is, as per [[basic.indet]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.indet#2), undefined behaviour.

> **[basic.indet]/1** When storage for an object with **automatic or dynamic storage duration** is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, **that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced** ([expr.ass]).
>
> **[basic.indet]/2** If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, **the behavior is undefined** except in the following cases:
>
> - [... none applies here]

Comment: Before I accept this answer, I wanted to look at the exceptions made for static storage (e.g. `static S s; assert(s.i == 0);` is well defined) and wanted to know if they applied here. I've not found that part yet though.

Comment: Although from your edit that's not looking likely.

Comment: @MikeVine Those exceptions are not really exceptions, but particular initialization rules that apply only to objects with static (or thread local) storage duration, as per [\[basic.start.static\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.start.static#2.sentence-2).

Comment: I think the crux of it is, that the standard phrase [`zero-initialised`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init) [which is what I want] and the general phrase "zero initialised memory" [which is what I have] dont necessarily match.

Comment: @MikeVine Indeed, and making assumptions about the connection between these two (particularly the misconception that the latter implies the former) is a very common cause of trying to analyze the behavior of undefined behavior. Whilst you could attempt to use `std::launder` before any read to the uninitialized vars to lower the risk of [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), you're still formally in the domain of UB.